Transform a matrix optimization problem into a semidefinite programming
I am working on a matrix optimization problem, and the constraints are difficult to handle.
The constraints are in the following form,
\begin{align}
\text{Given: } &b \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ , and } t \in \mathbb{R} \\\\
\text{Constraints: } & (b^T X^{-1} b)^2 < t^2 \\\\
\text{Variable: } &X \in \mathbb{S}^n \text{ (a real non-singular symmetric matrix, but not necessarily positive semidefinite)}
\end{align}
I have attempted to apply the properties of the Schur complements and formulate it as semidefinite programming.
\begin{align}
X \succ 0,\ b^T X^{-1} b < t \iff \begin{bmatrix}
t & b^T \\
b & X
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0
\end{align}
However, even if $X^2 \succ 0$, I found it hard to generalize this idea to my original problem, since
\begin{align}
(b^T X^{-1} b)^2 = b^T \underbrace{(X^{-1} bb^TX^{-1})}_{\text{singular}} b < t^2.
\end{align}
I wonder if there is some similar technique that can convert the original problem into an equivalent semidefinite programming, or if there are other approaches to solve the matrix optimization problem.
I appreciate any ideas or suggestions. Thanks in advance.
